# Can't install visual studio 2008 on my Windows 7 x64 PC

Tags: visual-studio

I got a new PC with the following features:
OS: windows 7 x64
CPU: Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-2500 CPU @ 3.30GHZ

the main page of the setup hangs on when trying to install VS2008. am not getting an error message. I am sure that the setup is not corrputed, because i used it to install VS2008 on other Windows7 x64 machine and it worked.

Note: that the installation process didnt start at all. And am using Admin account and lowered the UAC settings.

Any clues about this issue ? what i can do to get VS2008 installed on my new PC ?

Comment: Try on http://superuser.com. SO is for programming related questions.

Comment: While not strictly within the mandate of SO questions, I think this is by far the best place one could ask such a question. As such I won't vote to close. Installing an IDE is surely considered "programming related"

Comment: Bods, the third FAQ category is `software tools commonly used by programmers`. If VS isn't a tool used by programmers, who the heck is using it? :-)

Comment: @paxdiablo, by this I understand questions like: `What Tool to use for XXX?`, `How to write a plugin for the XXX tool I am using in order to integrate with CVS?` but definitely not `Why does my computer hang when installing XXX`.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using an extracted version from an ISO file you need run the setup.exe by mounting the ISO image to a drive using a sw such as Power ISO. Or else you can actually burn the files into a dvd and try running from it.

Answer (score 0):

Let it sit for a while, it may take some time on certain steps. If it is on the same screen for 1 hour, then you've got a problem.

Comment: I have mentioned that the settup is hanging on the main page. hence the instalation didnt start at all.

Answer (score 0):

Try applying the hotfix mentioned here: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/vssetup/thread/8952de62-8232-4a71-9535-1d3d46e6db2d

Answer (score 0):

Hi
In order to install vs 2008 on windows 7 64bit you need two things. an admin on the system and low user account control.
go to the user account control and lower the security to the lowest and then apply. it will remove the annoying questions that the windows is asking all the time.
you can restore it to the highest level afterwards if you want to.
Thanks

Comment: I updated my question and mentioned that am using Admin account and lowered the UAC settings to the minimum.